# express.js app.post middleware not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So this logs to my console:
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.method)
      console.log('why not working?')
    })

But this doesn't:

```
app.post(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method)
  console.log('why not working?')
})
```

Both demonstrate that the HTTP method is a POST

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you call it? Show code.

Comment: And, if this is supposed to be middleware, you will also need to either call `next()` or send a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.post` expect `path` as first parameter.

See more about it http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method

For example:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
});
```

In `app.use` `path` - optional argument, but in `app.post` it is required.

Comment: Ahhh, genius! : ) So, how do I ask for anything that's a post request?

Comment: check `req.method`? :)